# toggle between divs, but with default div when all closed

Tags: jquery

I'm trying make a toggle for multiple divs, but when all are closed I'm looking for it show a default div, the only one that would have been visible to begin with.

Any ideas? Thanks

html

```
<button type="button" id="loginButton" href=".loginSwap">Login</button><br/>
<button type="button" id="loginButton" href=".signupSwap">SignUp</button>
<div class='loginSwap ContentSwap' style='display:none'>Login Stuff</div>
<div class='signupSwap ContentSwap' style='display:none'>Signup</div>
<div class='defaultSwap ContentSwap'>Default Text</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("button").click(function(){
   var Swapper = $(this).attr("href")
    $(Swapper).slideToggle("fast");
    $(".ContentSwap:visible").not(Swapper).hide();

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qjdk655k/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the click handler, you can check whether the current item is already visible or not, if it is visible then toggle will hide it so we can show the default item(Assuming there will be only 1 item visible at any time)

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("button").click(function () {
        var Swapper = $(this).attr("href")
        var $swap = $(Swapper).stop(true, true),
            visible = $swap.is(':visible');
        $swap.slideToggle("fast");
        if (visible) {
            $(".ContentSwap.default").show();
        } else {
            $(".ContentSwap:visible").not(Swapper).hide();
        }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="loginButton" href=".loginSwap">Login</button>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="loginButton" href=".signupSwap">SignUp</button>
<div class='loginSwap ContentSwap' style='display:none'>Login Stuff</div>
<div class='signupSwap ContentSwap' style='display:none'>Signup</div>
<div class='ContentSwap default'>Default Text</div>
```